# Express module.js:550 throw err; ^ Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, npm, server

I'm trying to initialize a simple express app with the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
port = 3000


//creating the db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Criptare',{ useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true });
let db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,"connection error"));

//parsers 
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//session LATER


//static files
app.use('/static',express.static('public'));

//view engine PUG
app.use('view-engine','pug');

//Routes
const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main')
app.use(mainRoutes)

//error handle
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    let err = new Error('Looks like the page you were looking for was not found')
    err.status = 404;
    next(err)
})
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    res.locals.error = err
    res.status(err.status);
    res.render('error')
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`No bun serveru ii on pe ip-ul:localhost:${port}`)
})
```

After I run it with nodemon I get the following error:

```
module.js:550
throw err;
^
Cannot find module 'C:\Proiecte code\ON\express\criptare\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Anyone has any idea why I'm getting this?
I have all the dependencies inside the package.json

Comment: have you tried `npm install` already?

Comment: yes i've already did

Comment: I found the error , it was inside npm package main was set on index.js not app.js

Comment: instead of npm install try command "yarn" only

Answer (score 0):

Change directory to where your filename.js is located then,run node filename.js

Initialize npm in the current folder where the script is stored.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same issue. Running "yarn" fixed the issue

Comment: He stated that he is using npm.